# Program which behavior changes depending on classes it is linked against

Tags: c++, plugins, linker, extern

I do not think what I attempt is fancy enough to deserve the term "plugin"  but here what I am trying to do:

Given files a.h, a.cpp and main.cpp, I would like to create other files such as:

```
g++ -o test main.cpp a.cpp b.cpp
```

results in a test program doing something, and

```
g++ -o test main.cpp a.cpp c.cpp
```

does something else.

This part I already have working, cf code below.
My issue is: would it be possible to have

```
 g++ -o test main.cpp a.cpp
```

do some default behavior? I tried several things, but I always end up with something undefined.

Code I have so far:

```
// a.h    

#ifndef A_H_
#define A_H_

class A {
 public:
  A();
  ~A();
  virtual void print()=0;
};

#endif


// a.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "a.h"

A::A(){}
A::~A(){}


// b.h

#include "a.h"

class B: public A {
 public:
  B();
  ~B();
  void print();
};


// b.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "b.h"

B::B(){}
B::~B(){}
void B::print(){
  std::cout << "I am B" << std::endl;
}

A* a = new B();


//  code in c.h and c.cpp similar to the one in b.h and b.cpp
//   just "B" replaced by "C"

// main.cpp

#include "a.h"

extern A* a;

int main(){
  a->print();
}
```

When compiling against b.cpp, code prints "I am B", when compiling against c.cpp, code prints "I am C".

I would like:

```
g++ -o test main.cpp a.cpp
```

to have test either do nothing or do a default behavior. Does not need to be simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a (non-portable) option using weak symbols.

#### a.h

```
struct A {
  public:
    virtual void print() = 0;
};

struct Dummy: A {
  void print() override {};
};

A* init();
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include "a.h"

A* __attribute__((weak)) init()
{
  return new Dummy;
}

int main()
{
  A* a = init();
  a->print();
}
```

#### b.cpp

```
#include "a.h"
#include <iostream>

struct B: A
{
  void print() override {
    std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
  }
};

A* init()
{
  return new B;
}
```

If you don't link with `b.cpp` or any other entity that provides an `init` function, the one in `main.cpp` will be used. If you link with `b.cpp`, that one's definition will be used.

This sort of provides a "default implementation" for the `init` function, and lets you manage initialization by not using globals (not important here, but can get more tricky once you flesh out your plugin system).

Comment: looks great ! Not having any globals is a great plus. What do you mean by "non portable" ? Any limitation I should be aware of ?

Comment: The C (or C++) standards don't say anything about this sort of thing, so there are no portable solutions using this technique (there might be portable  solutions using other techniques, I'm just not aware of one though). The syntax is GCC syntax, clang probably supports it and maybe a few others. Won't work with e.g. MSVC, but other compilers/linkers probably have similar features.

Comment: seems to be working for me, but I will wait a little bit before accepting, just in case someone comes up with a more portable solution.